# after SP runs database table freeze

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have created a sp with select/update/fullouter join queries.
and also it has while loop running on temp table and inside loop i am inserting data to another table.

if i tried to select table from designer it show blank talbe even column heading a blank.
and alos can not open table for design , it is saying timeout.
but select query is running on table without issue.

if i close that query windows and then try to open the table then it is opening.

what is the reason for this.

Comment: Sounds like blocking - post your SQL code.

Comment: Without the code of the SP or an execution plan we can't be of much help..

Comment: Execute sp_who2 to find blocked and blocking processes and then use DBCC INPUTBUFFER(<blocking spid> | <blocked spid>) to find out which T-SQL statement are executed.